# Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, c++, dllexport

I am trying to pass a byte array to a c++ dll:

c++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* myfunction(byte bytes[])
{
    char *byteschar = (char*)bytes;
    //do somethings with it
    return byteschar;
}
```

c#:

```
[DllImport("mydll", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl
        ,CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string myfunction(byte[] bytes);
```

but I get a `System.AccessViolationException` when I call `myfunction`.

When I run the executable without the debugger it seems to be working fine

Comment: How does your C function know what size the array is?

Comment: I am converting the byte[] array to char pointer char* and after I am doing some operations on it I am returning it

Comment: So you are relying on a null-terminated string? Is your last byte in the array zero?

Comment: no, does casting it only work if it is null terminated? because when I run the executable without debugging it seems to be returning the desired string

Comment: Pass the length of the array also to `myfunction()`. Then use it to check the range of your indices while accessing it.

Comment: How is your C code going to know the length of your string? If you aren't passing in the length, the C code is assuming the string ends when it hits a zero byte. If you don't include that zero byte, the code will keep going past the end of the string until it hits a zero byte in some random data or crashes -- whichever happens first.

Comment: Ok so instead of casting the byte array to char* I used this `string s(reinterpret_cast< char const* >(bytes), length);` now I get this error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' `

Comment: Ok, so when I use Release mode it seems to be running fine, is it a must that I should handle this exception or is it not a critical one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a buffer be allocated in C# and filled in C++, the approach is a little bit different.

You should allocate a kind of "unmanaged" buffer, pass to the DLL and then convert the result and free the buffer. It's exactly the same way in C, but calling from a managed environment.

Your C++ code should be something like:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void myfunction(char* buffer, int length)
{
    //Fill buffer with something observing the maximum length of the buffer.
}
```

The signature of your DLL in C# should be:

```
[DllImport("mydll", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl
        ,CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern string myfunction(IntPtr buffer, Int32 length);
```

To call it from C#, you should do:

```
    IntPtr unmanagedBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100);
    // Your Unmanaged Call
    myfunction(unmanagedBbuffer, 100);
    string yourString = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedBuffer);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedBuffer);
```

Don't forget to call FreeHGlobal if you don't want a memory leak in your app. It's interesting to protect this in "try/finally" clauses.

Other observation is the encoding of the string. Uni, means Unicode. If you use another string representation, check for an equivalent PtrToStringXXX function.

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem, but in other comment I said it runs fine on build mode, is this error critical enough that I should handle it?

Comment: Yeah. Is the worst error ever. The C guys call it "undefined behavior". Is when you change memory areas that you are not supposed to change. You can predict what kind of behavior will happen in the following instructions, since you may have changed other variables data or even other processes data (what will cause a GPF and your app will break immediately).

Comment: The magic number 100 is the size of the buffer. Needs to be a size big enough to fit your data, but not so big that you can easily run out of memory

Answer (score 0):

It suppose to be:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* myfunction(unsigned char * bytes)
{
    //do somethings with it
    return bytes;
}
```